# Awk Match a TSV column and replace all rows with a prefix in bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a TSV file with the following format:

```
HAPPY    today I feel good
SAD    this is a bad day
UPSET     Hey please leave me alone!
```

I have to replace the first column value with a prefix like `__label__` plus my value to lower, so that to have as output

```
__label__happy     today I feel good
__label__sad     this is a bad day
__label__upset     Hey please leave me alone!
```

in the shell (using `awk`, `sed`) etc.

Comment: instead of `<tab>` you could have mentioned it is TSV (tab separated values) and do add the code you tried yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{ $1 = "__label__" tolower($1) }1' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>another awk</strike>

```
$ awk 'sub($1,"__label__"tolower($1))' file
```

with GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/[^t]+/__label__\L&/' file
```

Comment: It seems it loses that `<tab>` in this way. Possibile?

Comment: @loretoparisi it shouldn't lose the tab since the line is not rewritten, it might be version specific though, this works with `gawk`.

Comment: Should set FS to tab, since fields can contain spaces.. Also sed can be written more simplu as `sed -r 's/[^t]+/__label__\L&/'`

Comment: @123 golfing further - `sed 's/[^\t]*/__label__\L&/'` taking advantage of greediness

Answer (score 1):

Following awk may also help you in same too.

```
awk -F"\t" '{$1=tolower($1);printf("_label_%s\n",$0)}' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```